# #each inside another #each that is not a part of the first one handlebars

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I got a problem with displaying values inside "main" loop
my code looks like this:

```
{{# each movies}}
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                  <!--<img src="..." alt="...">-->
                  <div class="caption">
                    <h3><a href="/movie/{{this._id}}">{{this.title}}</a></h3>
                    <p>Rating :
                    {{#each ../ratings}}
                       {{this}}
                    {{/each}}
                    </p>
                    <p>Genre: <b>{{this.genre}}</b></p>
                    <p>{{this.description}}</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Modify</a> <a href="delete/{{this._id}}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Delete</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {{/each}}
```

And the problem is that I get all three values of "ratings" list inside the same block, but I want to get them separately one per each of movies. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you could post your json structure it would be helpful

Comment: there are two different json objects

Comment: You must provide a example, so someone could understand better what do you want to do.

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change my model and include rating field to it. So I didn't need the second each loop at all.